# Is it possible to determine the genomic context of a gene in a Whole Genome Shotgun project?

Tags: genome, wgs, scaffold

I performed several BLAST searches and identified several genes of interest in a Whole Genome Shotgun (wgs) project. I know that gene ***X*** is located on scaffold 1234, from nucleotide 1 - 2250, while gene ***Y*** is located on scaffold 2571, from nucleotide 3380 - 5790.

Given this information is it possible to determine if these genes are close to each other in the genome?

Many thanks for your help,

- Leah

Comment: great question.. i guess if you cannot assemble the contigs, chances are you are unlikely to get it from the current dataset.. which organism is this?

Comment: Thanks @StupidWolf! It is a wgs from an amoebozoan protist.

Comment: @michael, I would very much appreciate your thoughts on this question!